# Render Kaminari Pager Information In Builder.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I am trying to render the information from `paginate @objects` in a Rails 3.1 `index.builder` file.

I added the kaminari views to my app and created `_paginator.builder` in the kaminari directory which looks as follows:

```
xml.pager do
  xml.current_page current_page
  xml.last_page num_pages
  xml.per_page per_page
end
```

I then call `paginate @bjects` in `show.builder` which looks as follows

```
xml.instruct!

paginate @objects

xml.objects do
  @objects.each do |o| 
    xml.id o.id
    xml.name o.name
  end
end
```

When I call `paginate @objects` in my `index.builder` only the objects xml shows up, not the pager.

If I run `paginate @objects` during the request with Pry, I get

```
"<pager>\n  <current_page>1</current_page>\n  <last_page>14</last_page>\n  <per_page>20</per_page>\n</pager>\n"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually insert what paginate returns into the XML builder is generating, eg

```
xml << paginate(@objects)
```